# Save Window at Excel Report in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, model-view-controller, report

I have a working Excel Report code. Still, when I click the button the file goes directly to my download folder, without giving me the option to change its name or selecting where I want to save it.

Code is the following:

```
public void GetExcel()
{
    var list = (IList<LeaseViewModel>)Session["currentList"];
    var grd = new GridView { DataSource = list, AutoGenerateColumns = true };
    grd.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Leases.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    var swr = new StringWriter();
    var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(swr);
    grd.RenderControl(tw);
    Response.Write(swr.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
    tw.Close();
    swr.Close();
}
```

Can somebody please indicate what should I change in order to have the window popping?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Guess this is browser option. you should configure browser to ask you where to save a file.

Comment: I agree with @tchelidze

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everybody highlighting this is a browser-configuration issue.

I thought that once I have the definition of the default name in the code I could also define it to always ask what is the name I want. I tested in different browsers though, and fact is you were right, thanks for identifying it and noticing me.

Regarding the default name issue, here is how I solve it:

Before:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Leases.xls");
```

After:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Session["listName"] + "_Report.xls");
```

Now regardless the report I export, the name is always customized.

Hope it helps other newbies like me (: